# Can type aliases be used to define type aliases?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I tried to define a type alias by using another type alias, like so:

```
using pairs = Dictionary<string, int>;
using allPairs = Dictionary<string, pairs>;
```

and got this error message:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'pairs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

Why is this an error, and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No *using* alias can be used in the declaration of a using directive. As per [c# spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces#using-alias-directives),

> The order in which `using_alias_directives` are written has no
>   significance, and resolution of the `namespace_or_type_name`
>   referenced by a `using_alias_directive` is not affected by the
>   `using_alias_directive` itself or by other using_directives in the
>   immediately containing compilation unit or namespace body.

In other words, compiler process each `using alias directives` in isolation within a given declaration space. The result of this isolated processing within same declaration space, cause no knowledge on the existence of other `alias` in the given declaration space. Therefore, when you refer `alias` in another `using directive`, the compiler has no clue about the existence referenced alias.

```
using pairs = Dictionary<string, int>;
using allPairs = Dictionary<string, pairs>;
```

In the aforemention code, the second line will results in a compile-time error because it is not affected by the first using alias directive.

Answer (score 0):

Actually No. A using alias directive does not use the using directives in the source code file to resolve types Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246 for more information.